# Why copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator are being called for a single assignment operation?

Tags: c++

I am writing a class of String in c++ but I got confused when I saw that overloaded constructor and overloaded assignment operators were being called by a single assignment operation.
I am thinking that in b = "Check" line, string is first converted into String object hence overloaded constructor was called, then overloaded assignment operator was called.

```
String::String(const char* s)
{ 
    cout << "Overloaded Constructor::String\n";

        if (s != NULL)
        {
        size = strlen(s);
        bufferPtr = new char[size+1];
        strcpy(bufferPtr,s);
    }
    else
    {
        bufferPtr = NULL;
        size = 0;

    }

}

String & String::operator=(const String&rhs)
{
    cout << "Operator=::String\n";
   if (this != &rhs) // check same assignment
   { 
       size = rhs.size;
        delete [] bufferPtr;
        if(rhs.size != 0)
        {
            bufferPtr = new char[rhs.size+1];
            strcpy(bufferPtr,rhs.bufferPtr);
        }
        else bufferPtr = NULL;
    }
    return *this;
}

String a = "FName";
String b("LUsama");
b = "Check";
`
Output:
Overloaded Constructor::String
Overloaded Constructor::String
Overloaded Constructor::String
Operator=::String
```

Comment: What you were thinking, when you wrote the last sentence of your question, is correct.

Comment: Offtopic: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`) (unless coding for pre-C++11).

Comment: Offtopic2: I'd recomment to store capacity and size separately: if on assignment new size is smaller, you could reuse the old buffer (and wouldn't need to reallocate immediately, if you append next time). Or you reallocate only, if new size is less than a certain limit (e. g. half of current capacity). Additionally, as size is known anyway, I'd prefer `memcpy` over `strcpy` – this would cover embedded null characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see...

1. `a` constructor
2. `b` constructor
3. temporary object constructor (contains "Check" string)
4. temporary object is assigned to `b` via operator

Just as the output shows. What confuses you?